# SPRING WS misses "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>"

Tags: spring, soap, spring-ws

I use spring ws.

How could I add this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to my first line in the response?

I tried this block of code but It doesn't work. Could anybody help me?

```
@Bean (name = "messageFactory")
public SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory () {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, Boolean.TRUE);

    SaajSoapMessageFactory msgFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
    msgFactory.setMessageProperties(props);
    msgFactory.setSoapVersion(org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11);

    return msgFactory;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well at least it worked for me, thanks a lot !

I just changed the value from Boolean.TRUE to "true":

```
@Bean (name = "messageFactory")
    public SaajSoapMessageFactory messageFactory () {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, "true");

        SaajSoapMessageFactory msgFactory = new SaajSoapMessageFactory();
        msgFactory.setMessageProperties(props);
        msgFactory.setSoapVersion(org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_11);

        return msgFactory;
    }
```